# How to loop through object with 2 arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

Trying to loop throught State passed by props on other component

```js
state = {
    question:[firstQ, secondQ, thirdQ],
    tag:[[1,2,3],[4,6],[a,b,c,d]]
    }
```

I want to render it on next Componet with Patter like:

FirstQ

[tag1]

SecondQ

[tag2]

ThirdQ

[tag3]

etc
I was trying lot of option but getting always something like

FirstQ

SecondQ

ThirdQ

[tag1]

[tag2]

[tag3]

EDIT:

Passing data to second Component with

```js
question={this.state.question}
     tag={this.state.tag}
```

EDIT2:

For now i made loops like this

```js
{this.props.question.map((item,) => {
    return (<span key={item}>{item}</span>)
  })}
{this.props.tag.map((item) => {
    return (<span>{item<span>)
    })}
```

I trying to render this two arrays as pairs Question1 => Tag1 then underneath second Question2 = >tag2 etc.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Use the index of `question` to get matching tags

Something like:

```
{this.state.question.map((q,i)=>{
   return (
      <div>
        <h4>{q}</h4>
        Tags: {this.state.tag[i].join()}// map these to element you want instead of join()
     </div>
   )

})
```

Comment: I was trying similiar method, and it wasnt working...
This one dont throwing any error, thanks!